# Register event listeners in web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Is it possible to register listeners in a web worker to events other than `'message'` and `'error'`? E.g.

```
addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  postMessage('test');
});
```

**EDIT:**

According to @T.J.Crowder, it's not possible. However, in my case, I was able to emulate it with messages, somehow like this:

In the worker:

```
const handlers = {};

function registerKeyHandler(keycode, callback) {
  postMessage({
    type: 'REGISTER_KEY_HANDLER',
    keycode: keycode,
  });

  handlers[keycode] = handlers[keycode] || [];
  handlers[keycode].push(callback);
}

function onKeydown(keycode) {
  const hs = handlers[keycode] || [];
  hs.forEach(h => h());
}

self.onmessage = function(msg) {
  switch (msg.type) {
    case 'KEYDOWN':
      onKeydown(msg.payload.keycode);
      break;
  }
};
```

Outside:

```
worker.onmessage = function(msg) {
  switch (msg.type) {
    case 'REGISTER_KEY_HANDLER':
      window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode !== msg.keycode) {
          return;
        }
        worker.postMessage({
          type: 'KEYDOWN',
          keycode: msg.keycode,
        });
      });
      break;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Web workers don't have access to the DOM, not least because

- Allowing multiple threads to access the DOM opens up browser-based code to a whole new (and very tricky) class of multi-threading errors; allowing only the main UI thread to update the DOM avoids that
- Some browsers' DOM implementations can't handle access from multiple threads

The [global scope object](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#the-global-scope)* workers have isn't a window and only has the minimal features called out by the [web workers specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), such as `addEventListener` (although that's oddly only mentioned in passing in the spec), `postMessage`, the `onmessage` and `onerror` properties, etc.

* *(that's the common one, there are [dedicated](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#dedicatedworkerglobalscope) [for `Worker`] and [shared](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#sharedworkerglobalscope) [for `SharedWorker`] sub-interfaces depending on the type of worker)*